# Force Composable to take as much height as possible

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have a `@Composable` fun which renders the following view:

[image]

This is the code (without the bottom navigation though but that doesn't matter). The code can also be found in this reproduction project (just add your api key) https://github.com/Jasperav/GoogleMapsBug:

```
@Composable
fun ShowGoogleMap() {
    Scaffold {
        Column {
            GoogleMap()
            Text("hi")
            Text("hi")
            Text("hi")
            Text("hi")
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that `GoogleMap` does takes the whole height, it doesn't leave any space for the `Text`s.

How can I make sure `GoogleMap` shares the height with the other composables? I would expect to see the map with the other `Text`s stacked.

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: If this is the whole Layout, why do you need to use a `LazyColumn`? You can use a `Column` and give the map a weight to fill the screen leaving enough space for the other composables.

Comment: @Abhimanyu I don't really need the `LazyColumn`, I tried the `Column` way with various modifiers, but they all failed. The `GoogleMap` is taking up the whole screen when inside a `Column`.

Comment: @Abhimanyu I edited the question, please have another look

Comment: @ianhanniballake I added a sample code showing the `GoogleMap` is taking up all available space when inside a `Column`. Strange thing is, embedding `GoogleMap` inside a `LazyColumn` will make the `GoogleMap` as small as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How About this

```
Column(Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
            Box(Modifier.weight(1f)) {
                GoogleMap(Modifier.fillMaxSize())
            }
            Text("hi")
            Text("hi")
            Text("hi")
            Text("hi")
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add `Box` as a parent widget to column to use `Modifier.weight(1f)`.

```
@Composable
fun ShowGoogleMap() {
    Scaffold {
        Box(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f)) {
            Column {
                GoogleMap()
                Text("hi")
                Text("hi")
                Text("hi")
                Text("hi")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use modifier parameter of the GoogleMap composable to set it height

```
@Composable
fun ShowGoogleMap() {
    Scaffold {
        Column(
            // this will make the column size as the screen size
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
            // this will arrange items in the column evenly spaced
            // while keeping the first and last elements at extremes
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween

        ) {
            // adjust your map height size using the modifier
            GoogleMap(modifier = Modifier.height(400.dp))
            Text("hi")
            Text("hi")
            Text("hi")
            Text("hi")
        }
    }
}
```